# Editing metadata in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, metadata

How do I edit metadata in QGIS?

I found the plugin Metatools which is experimental and did not work for me.

In Metatools I always get the information

> ...unsupported metadata standard! Only ISO19115 supported now!

I then exported the metadata of the shapefile to xml with the same name as the shapefile, expecting to get the metadata in ISO standard but that is still not working.

My System:
Linux Mint 17; QGIS 2.6.0 Brighton; Metatool 0.3.0

Comment: Apparently that plugin has been updated now and is operational

Answer (score 1):

Metatools is somewhat limited. If you consider the possibility of a program outside QGIS, [CatMDedit](http://catmdedit.sourceforge.net/) is easy to use and with more capabilities.